# Is there any way/workaround to display images from formula field in Lightning:Datatable (aura component)?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-datatable

I have one component in which I have used lightning:DataTable aura component. All things are working fine until we display the image formula field. Is there any workaround to support the image formula field in aura lightning datatable component?

I have read somewhere in the blog that we can add the custome data type to display the image in datatable but this works with only LWC. I am looking for the aura component solution.

So, is there any way to add custom data type in lightning:datatable column?

FYI: I know there is idea for the same here:https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000lKqxQAE
I am looking for alternative solutions.

Comment: whats the issue with formula?

Comment: @PranayJaiswal It's displaying image URL instead of the image. I think it's just rendering the image formula field output as text.

Answer (score -1):

Displaying images in lightning:datatable is possible as mentioned in LWC component reference [refer to **Creating Custom Data Types** in this [link]](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/documentation). Although, it requires additional development, it seems to be possible.

Comment: Thank you for your comment but I am looking for aura component solutions.

Comment: lightning:datatable in aura doesn't seem to have the capability to handle images in its rows (atleast not in an effective way that I'm aware of). My intent of posting LWC reference link was that this functionality can be achieved in LWC with relatively lesser effort and you could wrap up the LWC data table inside your aura component.